# How to accept an answer to a question made as guest?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, unregistered-users

Yesterday I made a question on Chess Stack Exchange as a guest user (ChessNoob -
[How to avoid Pirc in favor of KID](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19475/how-to-avoid-pirc-in-favor-of-kid))
People answered and I'd like to accept one of the answers (the one made by user1583209) but I can't because it seems I already have another account registerd with the same email (the one I'm using now).
Maybe the solution to this kind of loop would be to add a check on the emails when posting as a guest?

Returning to the original question, how can I accept an answer if I made a question as a guest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [Contact Us](https://chess.stackexchange.com/contact) form and ask for your accounts to be merged. After that, you'll be able to accept the answer.

Comment: I'd like for most of my coworkers not to know it was me asking the question since it's rather critical of them.  Hence asking as a guest in order to ask anonymously.  I assumed that it would let me ask as a guest and yell at me about a duplicate email if that was a problem. How can I comment/edit as OP without de-anonymizing (which merging would do, no?)?

Comment: I think using another email account is your best bet.